# What DZ rank does 20+ DZ gear require?

Tags: the-division

I'm hanging out around level 19 in *The Division* waiting for my friend to catch up, so I'm running the Dark Zone. However, all the gear I can get from the vendor requires DZ rank 30. When I was 14, there was DZ-10 stuff, but now it's only DZ-30...

If I go up to the 20-24 bracket, will vendor gear require an even higher rank?

Answer (score 3):

**No.**

From my experience when your level is 1-15, DZ rank 10 and 30 gear will be available. When you're at level 16-29, only DZ rank 30 gear will be available. Once you reach rank 30, you also unlock high-end gear with DZ rank 50 but the DZ rank 30 gear doesn't go away.

*UPDATE:* this is about to change with patch 1.1:

> Ranks requirements for Superior and High-End quality items at the Dark
>   Zone Vendors have been adjusted:
>
> - Superior (Purple) items: Rank 15 instead of 30
> - High-End (Gold) level 30 (Gear Score 163): Rank 25 instead of 50
> - High-End (Gold) level 31 (Gear Score 182): Rank 40 instead of 50

Comment: I can't check right now, but im pretty sure, the northern areas are offering (safe rooms) DZ 50 stuff for DZ credits instead of Phoenix credits.